# VPS Server getting offline - CentOS

Tags: linux, mysql, vps

I have a VPS CentOS Server hosted by GoDaddy. The database for my website is going down once everyday. I have two websites hosted on that server, a Wordpress and a Magento website. The connection to database breaks everyday and both websites stop working. Both websites have daily auto-backups enabled. But the backups are not being created everyday and I believe that these auto-backups are preventing the server to keep in running state. Is there a way I can get to know why the server or database services are going down. I contacted GoDaddy but the guys said this is a Managed VPS plan and you are responsible if there is something wrong with the codes, and claimed that there is no issue with the server or database. They asked me to check the error logs (error_log, login_log and access_log). I am not sure if I have found anything. I have found these entries in error_log and login_log.

error_log

cpsrvd [1070] Shutting down due to SIGTERM or SIGINT

login_log

```
[2016-02-04 15:38:00 -0700] info [cpsrvd] 162.158.102.88 - phones "POST /login/?login_only=1 HTTP/1.1" FAILED LOGIN cpaneld: invalid cpanel user phones (loadcpdata failed)
[2016-02-04 23:37:25 -0700] info [cpsrvd] 162.158.102.88 - phon "POST /login/?login_only=1 HTTP/1.1" FAILED LOGIN cpaneld: invalid cpanel user phon (loadcpdata failed)
[2016-02-05 07:24:22 -0700] info [cpsrvd] 162.158.102.88 - root "POST /login/?login_only=1 HTTP/1.1" FAILED LOGIN cpaneld: access denied for root, reseller, and user password
[2016-02-05 15:17:51 -0700] info [cpsrvd] 162.158.102.88 - phonesta "POST /login/?login_only=1 HTTP/1.1" FAILED LOGIN cpaneld: invalid cpanel user phonesta (loadcpdata failed)
[2016-02-05 23:23:41 -0700] info [cpsrvd] 162.158.102.88 - phones "POST /login/?login_only=1 HTTP/1.1" FAILED LOGIN cpaneld: invalid cpanel user phones (loadcpdata failed)
[2016-02-06 07:51:29 -0700] info [cpsrvd] 162.158.102.88 - phon "POST /login/?login_only=1 HTTP/1.1" FAILED LOGIN cpaneld: invalid cpanel user phon (loadcpdata failed)
[2016-04-03 00:28:46 +0900] info [cpsrvd] 173.245.52.26 - phonesta "POST /login/?login_only=1 HTTP/1.1" FAILED LOGIN cpaneld: invalid cpanel user phonesta (loadcpdata failed)
[2016-04-03 00:28:47 +0900] info [cpsrvd] 173.245.52.26 - phonesta "POST /login/?login_only=1 HTTP/1.1" FAILED LOGIN cpaneld: invalid cpanel user phonesta (loadcpdata failed)
[2016-04-14 15:58:32 +0900] info [cpsrvd] 103.195.197.166 - bigsniphst "GET /cpsess4143108250/frontend/paper_lantern/index.html?login=1&post_login=13160154255724 HTTP/1.1" FAILED LOGIN cpaneld: cookie ip check: IP address has changed
[2016-04-14 15:58:38 +0900] info [cpsrvd] 103.195.197.166 - root "GET /cpsess2878390304/?login=1&post_login=81135025996821 HTTP/1.1" FAILED LOGIN whostmgrd: cookie ip check: IP address has changed
```

Is it possible that the resources are not sufficient and causing the outage?

Comment: Forgive me, but if this is a managed VPS, then they need to help you troubleshoot this, as it very well could be an issue with the server itself (i.e. running low on resources or something else). Do the websites crash at the same time every day, or does the time vary?

Comment: I am not sure whether this happens at the same time during backup. Don't know how to check that. And, as regarding Managed VPS, they offer server management services under their Fully Managed plans. In Managed plans developers must take care of the management. Under Managed VPS, they are offering me cPanel® | Patching | Security | Monitoring | Backups. Fully Managed gets me Dedicated team of server admin experts along with the others.

Comment: It turned out that the server is going offline every time backup is created. I changed the auto-backup settings. Today morning, I received alert that backup has failed and at same time the server went offline.

Answer (score 0):

login_log has nothing to with the mysql, if your database connection is breaking everyday that means there is something going on server which needs to troubleshooted at the earliest. The details provided by you here is very less to examine why mysql service is getting down on regular basis. As you said you have managed VPS from go-daddy, they should help you in this. As this thing comes under server administration.

Comment: I changed the backup settings yesterday, and today morning I received the email that backup has failed. At the same moment I checked my website and it was offline. So, every time the auto-backup triggers the database goes offline. I contacted GoDaddy support today and now they are saying that domain is pointing to a different IP address. However, website works smoothly after restarting server and mysql services. Files fetched on website are present only on this server. Could there be any chance of misconfiguration?

Comment: The different IP they mentioned is of CDN (CloudFlare) which is enabled for one of my websites. Some sort of fools sitting there at GoDaddy support. Everytime I contact them I get a different statement. If one says that the error log is filled up causing issues, the other says the website code is not optimized and is causing issues. There is nothing substantial I am receiving in response from GoDaddy.

Comment: It am sure that your mysql service is getting stopped everytime and whe you rebootthe server all services comes up. There is some issue with your database, may be there is some corrupted database which is responsible for stopping mysql service and backup failure. If you have csf installed in server you can switch on lfd alerts and if you have c-panel installed in your server you ca also contact them to support you. If this helps you out you can upvote my answer and comment

Comment: Could insufficient resources be the reason for database to go down? I am running a Wordpress and a Magento website running on my VPS. Allocated RAM is 1GB. Most of the time 65-70% memory is being used all the time. Could this be an issue while the backup is being created due to low available RAM?